# Groovy match doc files in folder

Tags: groovy

I am trying to know if a Pull Request in Github has to execute a pipeline in Jenkins or not (depending of pushing code or documentation). For that I have this function, but I am not able to math patterns this way:

- "i" is an array where each element is a modified file
- If the file is in doc/ or .github/ folder it is supposed to be documentation and no execution will be built in Jenkins.

I have made a change in .github/PULL_REQUESTS.md but this functions returns me FALSE

```
// Compares the modified files to see if it is only documentation
def checkPRDoc(String[] prChangeLog) {
    def pushing_doc = false
    println("Modified files:")
    for(int i in prChangeLog) { 
         println(i);
         if ((i ==~ /doc*/) || (i ==~ /README.md/) || (i ==~ /.github*/)) {
             pushing_doc = true
         }
         if (pushing_doc == false) {
             break;
         }
    }
    return pushing_doc
}
```

Any help? Thanks a lot

Comment: you did not specify the value example that not matches regexp. probably you want to use `=~` (find) instead of `==~` (full match)

Comment: Ops, sorry, probably I didn't explain well. The value example is ".github/PULL_REQUESTS.md"

Comment: `.` matches any symbol, `b*` matches `b` zero or more times... so it should be `==~ /\.github.*/`